# How to read a file & zip in node

Tags: node.js, zip

I'm working on a cross platform electron app.  The goal is to have a user add a video file within the app, zip that video & store it locally on the same machine.  Eventually these videos will be uploaded to a server

Right now the script below works fine for compressing text docs but as soon as I run a video through it I get the error:

> Unable to expand video_lossless.zip into zipped.  (Error 2 - no such
>   file or directory)

***Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?***

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var file = ['video_lossless', 'mov'];

var local = `./assets/${file[0]}.${file[1]}`;
var remote = `./assets/zipped/${file[0]}.zip`;

// creating archives
var zip = new AdmZip();

zip.addLocalFile(local);

zip.writeZip(remote);
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Probably you have not shared the entire code where you actually try to unzip that zip file?

Comment: I'm just double clicking in my mac finder window.  That's how the videos will normally be uncompressed.  I'm building a video delivery system that we can upload files to, then the client can download the zip, "double click" and see the unzipped video.